# Prove that the sequence $(3n^2+4)/(2n^2+5) $ converges to $3/2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Prove directly from the definition that the sequence $\left( \dfrac{3n^2+4}{2n^2+5} \right)$ converges to $\dfrac{3}{2}$.

I know that the definition of a limit of a sequence is $|a_n - L| < \varepsilon$ .

However I do not know how to prove this using this definition.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$,

$$\left|u_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{3n^2+4}{2n^2+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\frac{7}{4n^2+10}<\epsilon\iff 4n^2>\frac{7}{\epsilon}-10$$

so let $N=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left|\frac{7}{\epsilon}-10\right|}$ then forall $n>N$ we have $\left|u_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\epsilon$ and we conclude.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{3n^2+4}{2n^2+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right| = \left|\frac{6n^2+8-6n^2-15}{4n^2+10}\right| = \frac{7}{4n^2+10}$$

How would we continue?

Comment: are we not supposed to divide by the highest power to start with? would that not make the process easier? :S

Comment: Not if one isn't familiar with limit arithmetic, as I gathered from the instructions to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: for an arbitrary $\,\epsilon>0\;$ :

$$\left|\frac{3n^2+4}{2n^2+5}-\frac32\right|=\left|\frac{-7}{2(2n^2+5)}\right|<\epsilon\iff2n^2+5>\frac7{2\epsilon}\iff$$

$$(**)\;\;2n^2>\frac7{2\epsilon}-5\ldots$$

Be sure you can **prove** you can choose some $\,M\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. for all $\,n>M\;$ the inequality (**) is true.

Comment: +1 Will the OP be faced the floor function while finding the proper $n$?

Comment: That's one possibility, @BabakS.  Another one is to take a square root and then add to it 1 or even 2 so as to be completely sure we get naturals for which the condition is true. Since we're usually interested to prove the existence of *some* such $\,M\,$ we don't have to be thrifty...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that it does not converge to $3/2$. Then you have that there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $|\displaystyle \frac {3n^2+4}{2n^2+5} - \frac {3}{2}|\geq \varepsilon_0 $ which is equivalent to $\displaystyle \frac {7}{4n^2+10}\geq \varepsilon_0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ which is not true since we can make the fraction as small as we like so the sequence is convergent and the limit is $3/2$.

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Babak S. Well, I love to assume that it is not to prove that it is.

Answer (score 1):

The following computation proves the claim
$$\left|\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3n^2 + 4}{2n^2+5}\right| = \left|\frac{(6n^2+15)-(6n^2+8)}{4n^2+10}\right| = \left|\frac{7}{4n^2+10}\right|\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
The same computation shows that in general if you have two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of the same degree $m$, then $\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$ converges to $\frac{p_m}{q_m}$, where $p_m$ is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $P$ and similarly for $Q$.

Comment: To write as given the rightmost limit assumes the OP alreay knows how to calculate it...but if he already knows how to calculate it then his question is superfluous.